# Limit which roles can view a node basing on its content type

Tags: users, nodes

I'm using Drupal 7 and I created a new content type called "eBook," and I created a new role called "MonthlySubscriber." My intention is to allow only users with the "MonthlySubscriber" to view the "eBook" nodes. When I looked at the permission settings for a role, I saw the checkboxes that allows to create, edit and delete nodes of that content type, but there are no checkboxes for viewing nodes.

How do I limit the users who can view "eBook" nodes to just the users with the "MonthlySubscriber" role?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to install [Content Access](http://drupal.org/project/content_access) module to add this access control.

> This module allows you to manage permissions for content types by role
>   and author. It allows you to specifiy custom view, edit and delete
>   permissions for each content type.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple way protect node pages (node/NID) from unprivileged users.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_alter().
 */
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['node/%node']['access callback'] = 'mymodule_check_node_access';
}

/**
 * Determines whether the current user may perform the operation on the node.
 */
function mymodule_check_node_access($op, $node) {
  if ($node->type == 'protected_type' && !user_access('administer site configuration')) {
    return FALSE;
  }
  return node_access($op, $node);
}
```

Comment: Note that using `hook_node_access` will not work with anything that "lists" nodes, like a View. So you may restrict view access in `hook_node_access`, but a View or custom node query may still show that node to the user. `hook_node_access` is more useful for editorial control, for controlling create/update/delete operations

Comment: Your code doesn't work for me, but you pointed me in the right direction. I found working code on the hook_node_access documentation https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7

Comment: This is a bad example because it use mymodule_node_access as custom function while Drupal provides a hook_node_access hook. This can become confusing.

Comment: @batigolix, as stated in the answer it is a way to protect node pages not nodes.

Answer (score 5):

For drupal 7, try using [hook_node_access()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_access().
 */
function YOURMODULE_node_access($node, $op, $account) {
  if (
    $node->type == 'ebook' &&
    $op == 'view' &&
    !in_array('MonthlySubscriber', $account->roles)
  ) { return NODE_ACCESS_DENY; }
  return NODE_ACCESS_IGNORE;
}
```

Comment: Please avoid code-only answers. They serve no learning purpose. At least explain in a sentence or three how exactly this particular code is an answer? How does it work? why it works? The kind of description that will help others to write similar code in similar situation ,instead of asking again and again.

Comment: This should be the correct answer.

Comment: Don't forget to clear your cache after any code changes here.

Answer (score 2):

Content Access didn't work for my Drupal 7 install, so I used [Node View Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/node_view_permissions) instead.

Answer (score 1):

For drupal 7, try this one: [Access by Term](http://drupal.org/project/abt)

> Provides very flexible, hierarchical node access control (content access control), for D7.

Answer (score 1):

I perfer using the [Node View Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_view_permissions) module. It's simpler than the Content Access module.

As in D6, it adds "View any content" and "View own content" permissions to any content type that you choose.

[image]

Steps to follow:

1. After installing and enabling, go to
   `/admin/config/content/node-view-permissions` and select which
   content types that you want to limit access to.
2. Then, go to `/admin/people/permissions#module-node_view_permissions`
   and select the roles that you want to be able to view the content. Save permissions.

   Done!

Comment: for drupal 8 "Node View Permissions "  is not working

Comment: @KarthikeyanManivasagam How so?

Comment: We used this module in one of our project where we need to provide content view access based on  role and content type, but its not working  at all. it behaves remains the same like without using this module.

Answer (score 0):

The hook_menu_alter solution posted above by ya.teck does work, but conflicts with the standard hook_node_access in its function name. the hook_menu_alter is not required in this case, and so the answer posted by Denis above is in my opinion more accurate and the proper way. Altering the menu_item as is done is the first referenced example could be clobbered by another module further down the pipe.

Answer (score 0):

I used a code snippet found in the D7 api documentation for the [hook_node_access hook](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7.x).

This code will grant access to view "ebook" content to users that have the "view ebook" permission.

You need a new permission to control access by implementing hook_permission().

```
/**
 * Implements hook_permission().
 */
function mymodule_permission() {
  return array(
    'view ebook' => array(
      'title' => t('View Ebook'),
      'description' => t('View Ebook nodes.'),
    ),
  );
}
```

By implementing hook_node_access() Drupal can grant or deny the access to the node.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_access().
 */
function mymodule_node_access($node, $op, $account) {

  // Checks for an ebook node in view mode.
  if (is_object($node) && $node->type === 'ebook' && $op === 'view') {

    // Grants permission to view the node if the current user has an role
    // with the permission 'view ebook'.
    if (user_access('view ebook')) {
      return NODE_ACCESS_ALLOW;
    }

    // Otherwise disallows access to view the node.
    return NODE_ACCESS_DENY;
  }
  // For all other nodes and other view modes, don't affect the access.
  return NODE_ACCESS_IGNORE;
}
```

Other permissions (edit, delete, etc) can be dealt with via the normal Drupal permissions.

Optionally you can remove the content from the admin overview by implementing hook_query_TAG_NAME_alter.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_query_TAG_NAME_alter().
 */
function mymodule_query_node_admin_filter_alter(QueryAlterableInterface $query) {
  if (!user_access('view ebook')) {
  $query->condition('n.type', 'ebook', '!=');
  }
}
```