# Drupal 7, hook permission for view published content only for certain content type/blog

Tags: hooks, users

I disabled the view published permission for anonymous user. but I wanted to allow anonymous user to view the blog section with views on it, and I cant seem to hook permission on that particular blog.

is there any clue for this?

thank you

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7056/permission-to-view-nodes-of-a-content-type-in-drupal-7

Answer (score 0):

You can use [content_access](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access) module, you can control any content type permissions individually. [here is a nice video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VSQ4L7wADnc)